# unexpected inefficiency of a motor driver

Tags: motor, h-bridge

I purchased one of [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10pcs-lot-L9110S-DC-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Board-H-Bridge-L9110-for-arduino-Free-Shipping-Dropshipping/32251090078.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10324_10342_5000018_5060018_10547_10325_10343_51102_10340_10341_10548_5130018_10192_10190_10084_10083_10307_10301_10303_10312_10059_10313_10314_10184_10534_5790011_100031_10604_10103_10594_10142,searchweb201603_6,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=650c64a3-063a-449d-94a0-c77e6faf2a4b-3&algo_pvid=650c64a3-063a-449d-94a0-c77e6faf2a4b&rmStoreLevelAB=5) motor drivers and noticed that i was not getting as much time from my battery as i had expected. I tested the current draw when connecting my motor directly to the battery and then when connected via the controller. the results were disappointing, i got 70mA direct connection and 144mA using the controller so more than double the current! i then tried through a mosfet and that was good, 73mA.
If i want to get a more efficient circuit am i going to have to build an h-bridge myself or am i just using a rubbish controller? Thanks

Comment: How did you measure the current?  Were you seeing those values as peaks?   Can you please post some waveforms?

Answer (score 1):

You connected your (one) motor to the battery and got 70mA draw. You use a **two motor** driver and are seeing 144mA draw. I'm not sure what the problem is. What command are you sending to the second motor?